# Sending a nagios alert when graphite does not get data

Tags: monitoring, nagios, graphite

I am collecting some metrics using graphite, but sometimes there is no data coming into it (probably because the server has gone down, or no network connectivity). I want nagios to send me an alert during such an event. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the check_file_age script from nagios-plugins to check a single known datapoint of interest per system that you are collecting data from.

```
check_file_age -w 600 -c 1800 /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/servers/$(uname -f)/cpu/idl.wsp
```

That would alert you if a certain metric was missing within 5 minutes.

Else

You could run a find command over all the points, and report any that have not been updated in n hours.

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD_GRAPHS=$(find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -mmin +120 -type f | wc -l)
if [[ OLD_GRAPHS -gt 0 ]];then
  echo "Found ${OLD_GRAPHS} graph(s) without an update in 120 minutes"
  exit 1
fi
echo "All graphs are up to date"
exit 0
```

Comment: I think this solution should work, but i'm getting a problem.. When I run the command manually it works. But Nagios is giving some error. This is what I get in the log -    Embedded Perl ran /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_file_age: return code=2, plugin output=FILE_AGE CRITICAL: File not found - -w\n